# Zuul Routing in one place in deferent micro serrvice

Tags: routes, spring-cloud, properties-file, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

This is part of my .yml file in edge service.

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: /admin
  routes:
    user-detail-service: /users/**
    products-service: /products/**
  strip-prefix: false
  prefix: /api
```

I use Eureka server for registration.  now I can use localhost:8082/api/products/products  and get data from products-service. is there any method to  refer my services like localhost:8082/api/products and get product data from products-service.

I have linked this with my repo  https://github.com/ThamiraWeerkoon/ShoppingMall
in that repo has all the micro services.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `strip-prefix: true` in your configuration or just leave it blank since `true` is the default value.

Comment: i changed that default value in bottom part. Thats why i change that value for true. now i edit it. can you understand my problem now